# What does wp-list.js do?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Pretty straightforward question!

What does wp-list.js do?

It's listed in the wp_enqueue_script codex page as one of the WP included javascript libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This file is for list manipulations with jQuery: add, delete or dim list items. It was introduced in [Ticket #4805](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4805) to replace some prototype code.

Attached to the ticket is a sample plugin which holds the actual documentation. It doesn’t work really good … line 461 should be:

```
    $id = isset ( $_POST['id'] ) ? (int) $_POST['id'] : 0;
```

But at least you can test what the code really does in a reduced example.

[image]

The readable code for the file is in `wp-includes/js/wp-lists.dev.js`.